# Definition of pi by an integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definition, pi

I read [here](http://math.caltech.edu/~nets/lecture19.pdf) that we may define function,

$$ \arcsin a := \int_{0}^a \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx$$
This is what I understood: I believe the domain is for $ a \in [0,1)$, since integrand is continuous on $[0,a]$ so the Riemann Integral makes sense. When $a=1$, we define $$\arcsin 1= \frac{\pi}{2} := \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dx$$

Why can we do this? Firstly, we don't know the integral exists?

I do see by MCT of Lebesgue Integral, $\arcsin a \rightarrow \arcsin 1^+$. But is this finite?

---

Answer (score 1):

The function 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ is summable near the point $x=1$ (check this by integrating the last expression).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So to make sense of the integral, we are working with Lebesgue integral? Since the integrand is not a bounded function..

Comment: you don't need to use Lebesgue integral. You can just take the limit as $a\to 1^-$ of the integral.

Comment: Just to clarify, we define $\arcsin 1 := \lim_{a \rightarrow 1^-} \arcsin a$. This is well defined as for sequence $a_n \rightarrow 1^{-}$, $\arcsin a_n$ has limit $\alpha < \infty$ and this limit is unique. Is this right?